# Simple ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My question looks very simple, but strangely nothing that I've tried works.

I just want to load some partials with ajax. I've divided a template into several requests so that the page is loaded one part at a time. Specifically, I would like the `#footnotes` element to be loaded as an ajax request.

The parent template `services/index.html.haml` looks like this:

```
.services
  - @services.each do |service|
    .service= service.name
      #footnotes
```

Once the `#footnotes` element loads, I'd like to launch an ajax call that would load `services/_footnotes.html.haml` into it.

Here's `services/_footnotes.html.haml`:

```
- @footnotes.each do |footnote|
  .footnote= footnote
```

In `ServicesController` there's an action that hopefully should render my `services/_footnotes.html.haml`:

```
  def footnotes
    stop_id = params[:stop_id]
    service_ids = params[:service_ids].split(/,/)
    @footnotes = ServicesHelper.generate_footnotes(service_ids, stop_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @footnotes }
    end
  end
```

I've tried some javascript solutions from various answers that I've read. One of the javascript solutions I've tried and failed with was:

```
$("#services").ready(function () {
    $(".service").each(function(index, element) {
        var stop_id = $("#stop_id").data("stopid");
        var service_ids = $(element).data("serviceids");
        $("#footnotes", element).getJson("/stops/" + stop_id + "/services/" + service_ids + "/footnotes");
    });
});
```

This particular solution generates the error `Object [object Object] has no method 'getJson'`.

It seems that I'm failing to grasp how this really works. What am I doing wrong? What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is

`$.getJSON`

and NOT getJson

So,

```
$.getJSON("your-json-url-here", function(data) {
    //Do stuff on data!
});
```

See here: [jquery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but this still gives the same error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'getJSON'` and it doesn't answer my question as to what's the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer to correct the call. I am sorry I have no clues how rails work!

Comment: Edited to add an example JSON call.